# Why there are 10 pregenerated OutOfMemoryError instances?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

I took a look on simple java application heap dump. I know that OutOfMemoryError object is being created at application startup. But I found ten instances of OutOfMemoryError class in heap dump. Why do we need more than one?

Comment: How many threads did your code run at point of dump? Might there be one preconstructed oome per thread? The preconstruction itself of cause makes sense - no way to throw something you canmot create due to no memory...

Comment: if you have the heap dump why not just analyze what's referencing those objects?

Comment: I have just one thread. Some instances contains different detailMessage (String field), some contain null in that field.

Comment: You may be using one thread, but Java itself also creates a number of threads.

Comment: If you can examine the instances, check [their detail messages](http://java.sys-con.com/node/1229281). Some examples are `Requested array size exceeds VM limit` or `PermGen space`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because creating an OutOfMemoryError uses memory and if you don't have any memory left, you can't create it when needed.

Why there is 10, may be due to either the message or the stack trace being different, or they could be consolidated but haven't been.